# can i validate xhtml programmatically from a php script?

Tags: php, validation, xhtml

I would like to have a PHP function to check if a URL returns valid HTML or NOT, and returns true or false.

Something like:

if (validate_page("/somefile.html")) { echo "This page validated!!"; }

I found TWINE but it doesn't just give me true or false. Also I got an error running it on my system. http://twineproject.sourceforge.net/

I found this offline tool that looked promising. http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/offline/

Also I found this thread that talks about a gem, but it sounds problematic. [How do I validate XHTML with nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287952/how-do-i-validate-xhtml-with-nokogiri)

Comment: The thread talking about a gem is about Ruby (a gem is a package), not PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [W3C's validator API](http://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html). There's a PHP library available through PEAR ([click here](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_W3C_HTMLValidator)) which uses said API.

You can also install the validator on your local server ([instructions here](http://validator.w3.org/docs/install.html)), though you might not have sufficient permissions to do so if you are using shared hosting.

Comment: This is what I ended up using, thanks for this answer. Sorry for belated response

Answer (score 2):

Tidy?

Validate: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.tidy-diagnose.php
Repair: http://us.php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairstring.php

Comment: this looks promising, I'll try it out!

Answer (score 1):

You could also try `DOMDocument->validate()` if you are using PHP 5 and if the document contains a DTD.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.validate.php

Answer (score 0):

xhtml hast to be valid xml - if you only want to check that, you could easily use [simplexml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), but if you also want to check for correct elements/attributes this won't help you (in that case, NullUserExceptions hint to W3C's validator API would be the best solution to choose).

Answer (score 0):

```
libxml_use_internal_errors ( true );
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc -> loadHTMLFile ( $file ); // load the file you want validated
var_dump ( libxml_get_errors () );
```

Comment: Thanks for this code sample! I got this working, but it gave me a false positive on one of my test cases. Also it only works on static fules (not php templates). But good enough for now, thanks!