# Find what part of Html is invalid with PHP

Tags: php, html

I tried several methods to find out what part of a html string is invalid

```
$dom->loadHTML($badHtml);
$tidy->cleanRepair();
simplexml_load_string($badHtml);
```

None is clear regarding what part of the html is invalid. Maybe and extra config option for one of the can fix that. Any ideas ?

I need this to manually fix html input from users. I don't want to relay on automated processes.

Comment: I think that it is useless idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [can i validate xhtml programmtically from a php script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714819/can-i-validate-xhtml-programmtically-from-a-php-script)

Comment: You might want to considering using W3C's source code. This was implemented for a project I once worked on - http://nibbler.silktide.com/

Comment: You might want to specify what kind of output you expect from this function.

Comment: I don't think it's a dup. I need to find the error not fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try loading the offending HTML into a DOM Document (as you are already doing) and then using simplexml to fix things. You should be able to run a quick diff to see where the errors are.

```
error_reporting(0);

$badHTML = '<p>Some <em><strong>badly</em> nested</stong> tags</p>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->encoding = 'UTF-8';

$doc->loadHTML($badHTML);

$goodHTML = simplexml_import_dom($doc)->asXML();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare cleaned and bad version with [PHP Inline-Diff](http://software.zuavra.net/inline-diff/) found in answer to that [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321294/highlight-the-difference-between-two-strings-in-php).

Comment: Is there an option to preserve html tags and show the difference between strings that have html ?

Comment: Maybe try use function `strip_tags`