# Is there a "proper" way to test HTML validity?

Tags: html, rspec2, w3c-validation

I am trying to include HTML validity to our suite of tests (RSpec) with the w3c_validator gems. One problem is the lag between my machine and the W3C servers (the gem uses remote validation). Another problem is that I would like the HTML errors to be displayed as some kind of warning instead of spec failures.

**What would be the proper way of achieving this?**

**Versions:**

```
RSpec 2.7
Rails 3.0.4
Ruby 1.8.7
Ubuntu Linux (11.04)
```

Comment: you could try using Nokogiri, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287952/how-do-i-validate-xhtml-with-nokogiri

Comment: I believe that [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.rubyforge.org/) can also generate validation errors (I could be wrong, though).

Answer (score 0):

One way: use [v.Nu](https://validator.github.io/validator/).

For example:

1. Install `vnu.jar` on your computer to reduce the lag.
2. Run `vnu.jar` as a [standalone web service](https://validator.github.io/validator/#standalone).
3. Write your own code (say, in Ruby) to use the [v.Nu HTTP interface](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Service:-Input:-POST-body) and display the errors as you like.

Depending on what you mean by "proper", which can include requirements that are specific to your needs and circumstances, v.Nu has a strong case for being the proper way to validate (X)HTML(5). For links to information that support this case, and an example use of the v.Nu HTTP interface, see [linter-vnu](https://atom.io/packages/linter-vnu).