# Nokogiri losing attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I simply try to proxy a website with parsing using nokogiri.

**My controller action**

```
des show
  @url                = 'http://www.femmeactuelle.fr/'
  @with_nokogiri      = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@url).read).to_html
  @without_nokogiri   = open(@url).read

  if params.has_key? :nokogiri
    render text: @with_nokogiri, layout: false
  else
    render text: @without_nokogiri, layout: false
  end
end
```

If I use this action with **?nokogiri=foo**, the body loses its id.  Any idea for what reason?
I simply want the same html as that the browser sees after parsing with nokogiri.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'losing id'?  What result are you seeing, and what are you expecting?

Comment: Still not following you, can you post an HTML snippet of what you are seeing that looks wrong/different, and what you expect it to look like?

Comment: I'm doing some change on the html like image replacement, rewrite link to css/js but I don't know why it loosing the id on the body after processing with nokogiri.

Comment: You mean that `<body id='foo'>` is being rendered as `<body>`?

Comment: Yes that's why I mean.

Comment: open() come from open-uri

Comment: There are many tags that have not been closed properly. You also have embedded unescaped XHTML inside of `script` tags.  Run the document through an XML validator and fix all these, post back when done.

Comment: Thanks, sounds good. Any ruby library advice me ? When I run .validate on the nokogiri object it send me Nil.

Comment: See an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287952/how-do-i-validate-xhtml-with-nokogiri

Comment: The validate is empty so it's not come from invalid html, don't you think @PinnyM ?

Comment: `validate` was very not empty when I tried... not sure how else to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't duplicate a problem with Nokogiri stripping an `id` parameter from a `<body>` tag in valid HTML. Here's my Nokogiri/LibXML and Ruby particulars:

```
nokogiri: 1.5.9
ruby:
  version: 1.9.3
  platform: x86_64-darwin10.8.0
  description: ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
  engine: ruby
libxml:
  binding: extension
  compiled: 2.7.7
  loaded: 2.7.7
```

Here's a simple test of Nokogiri:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<html><body id="foo">bar</body></html>')

puts doc.to_html
```

Returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body id="foo">bar</body></html>
```

When I parse 'http://www.femmeactuelle.fr/', Nokogiri's `errors` method returns a number of errors, including in the `<head>` and `<body>`. Nokogiri tries to fix the document when it is broken, which can result in tags being moved, or, as I suspect in this case, parameters getting lost.

[Validating the document](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.femmeactuelle.fr%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) returns all sorts of errors, so I think the problem lies outside of Nokogiri. If you want to try to fix it before passing it to Nokogiri, you can send the file through HTMLTidy, and then see if Nokogiri can make better sense of it. Otherwise, spend some time digging through the HTML, figure out what's broken, and write some string manipulation code to patch it up.

You can't compare the source of a page that a browser renders with what a parser, like Nokogiri, outputs. They are very different pieces of code, with very different goals. A browser wants to make the page render something, and has all sorts of fall-backs for dealing with broken HTML. A parser doesn't, because its job is to accurately translate the HTML or XML into its true structure so we can dig through it.